# Reset text color to default after span insertion

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I get back the normal text color after insertion of span. Anything I type after the span just retains the span colour.

```js
function insertSpan() {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.style.color = "red";
  var r = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  r.surroundContents(span);
  span.textContent = "<insert text>";
  document.querySelector("div").focus();
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Your text here</div>
<button onclick="insertSpan()">Insert span</button>
```

Comment: At least in your example it does not retain color. Check what HTML is generated in your local environment

Comment: @Justinas the text added to the end of the string in the div after insertion is always in the span colour

Comment: Well, if you click _inside_ span and start writing text there, it will be contained in that span and will have red color.

Comment: @Justinas, Maybe I phrased it wrongly,Suppose the text is 'Your text here <insert text> asdasd' , if i start typing after <insert text>,(asdasd, which should be defaulted) for example, ends up in the span as well, is there any way to default the text that comes after the span, seems to consider it as part of the span. Thanks!

Comment: Because, when you click next to the `>` as in `<insert text>|` (| = cursor) you are actually still clicking *inside* the span - or at least, that's how the browser is interpreting where you are clicking.  That's just how the browser works, and it's annoying.

Comment: And that's just the behavior you have in every Web-Text-Editor

Comment: also, you should append you span in a different way. As per your current code, if I select the button's text and then click, the new `<span>` gets inserted inside the button.

Answer (score 0):

You may add an extra white space at the end of the contenteditable div eachtime you fire insertSpan().

possible example:

```js
function insertSpan() {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.style.color = "red";
  var r = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  r.surroundContents(span);
  span.textContent = "<insert text>";
  document.querySelector("div").focus();
  document.querySelector("div[contenteditable").appendChild(document.createTextNode("\u00A0"));
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Your text here</div>
<button onclick="insertSpan()">Insert span</button>
```